# problem when i open video in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

i used this way to make a video layout but the problem is that whenever  i try to open the video it says "can't be opened", but when i open the layout the music in my phone stop working,and i checked the format of the video made it the same as the one android phone uses
is there another way ?
java

```
package com.example.kingbio;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity  {
VideoView videoView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    ImageButton imageButton3 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    imageButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openMainActivity();
        }
    });
    videoView =findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String videopath ="android.resource//"+getPackageName() + "/" 
    +R.raw.first;
    Uri uri= Uri.parse(videopath);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.start();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "first/mp4");
    videoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Log.d("video", "setOnErrorListener ");
            return true;
        }
    });
    MediaController mediaController =new MediaController(this);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
}
public void openMainActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fbf2da"
tools:context="com.example.kingbio.Main3Activity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="136dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/vid"
    android:textColor="#aa926f"
    android:textSize="50sp" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_width="129dp"
    android:layout_height="77dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@id/videoView"
    android:background="#fbf2da"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_left_black_24dp"
    tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat"
    android:contentDescription="@string/previous"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/textView2" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="129dp"
    android:layout_height="77dp"
    android:background="#fbf2da"
    android:contentDescription="@string/next"
    android:layout_below="@id/videoView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView2"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_24dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,VectorDrawableCompat"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/textView2" />
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="569dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:layout_width="119dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/videoView"
    android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/textView2"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView2"
    android:background="#fbf2da"
    android:contentDescription="@string/back"
    app:srcCompat="?attr/actionModeCloseDrawable" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

i really need some help i don't know what i'm doing wronging, if there is an easy why please help.

Answer (score 0):

hi if you have problem in playing video of format .mp4 try this piece of code

```
VideoView view = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_file;
view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
view.start();
```